# When I typed this it gave me "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Tags: android, kotlin

```
package com.example.myandroidapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val calButtonVar = findViewById(R.id.calButton) as Button
        var radiusTextvar = findViewById(R.id.radiusText) as EditText
        var areaTextvar = findViewById(R.id.areaText) as TextView

        calButtonVar.setOnClickListener{
            var calArea: Double = 3.14 * radiusTextvar.text 
            areaTextvar.text = calArea.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

at calArea is where the error appears, i tried swapping var with val but it didnt work so I dont know what should I do and I also looked for similar problems but they didnt have it like me

Comment: You are trying to multiply a number (`3.14`) by an `Editable`. That is not going to work.

Comment: is it possible if you give me a solution?

Comment: `val calArea = 3.14 * (radiusTextvar.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As @CommonsWare wrote you can't just multiply editable text. use this instead:
var calArea: Double = 3.14 * radiusTextvar.text.toDouble()

Comment: i actually tried that and it gave me that it is wrong

Comment: Since `radiusTextvar` is an `EditText`, to parse it into a `Double`, you would need to use `radiusTextvar.text.toString().toDouble()`. Or, better yet, use `radiusTextvar.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()`, which will evaluate to `null` if the text in the field is not a valid floating-point number.

Comment: Hello thanks a lot actually your way worked, I really appreciate it